# What xpath can I use to map multiple records in reverse order (starting with the last record and ending with the first)?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am currently using: loadTable:Import[@source='People']/rep/employment_history/employment

The language am I using allows me to grab all records in the XML and maps them in order from first to last.  Is there additional language that would allow me to map this starting with the last record and ending with the first record?

This xpath needs to apply to hundreds of people, so the amount of records is not always 3, but I always need them in the reverse order in which they appear.

**XML below:**

```
-<Import firmCrd="0" date="6/17/2013" source="People">
  -<rep xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     -<employment_history>-<employment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><employment_id>51379</employment_id><rep_id>14718</rep_id><emp_seq>1</emp_seq><employer_name>Fake Name</employer_name><biz_type/><employee_title>OTHER - HOME PARTY CONSULTANT INDEP. C</employee_title><street1/><street2/><city>SAN DIEGO</city><state>CA</state><zip/><country/><start_date>1988-01-01T00:00:00</start_date><end_date>1989-09-01T00:00:00</end_date><inv_related>0</inv_related><crd_seq_num>1</crd_seq_num></employment>
   -<employment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><employment_id>51380</employment_id><rep_id>14718</rep_id><emp_seq>2</emp_seq><employer_name>UNEMPLOYED</employer_name><biz_type/><employee_title>OTHER</employee_title><street1/><street2/><city>WILMINGTON</city><state>MT</state><zip/><country/><start_date>1988-01-01T00:00:00</start_date><end_date>1989-09-01T00:00:00</end_date><inv_related>0</inv_related><crd_seq_num>3</crd_seq_num></employment>
   -<employment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><employment_id>51381</employment_id><rep_id>14718</rep_id><emp_seq>3</emp_seq><employer_name>PIZZA HUT</employer_name><biz_type/><employee_title>OTHER - WAITRESS</employee_title><street1/><street2/><city>ALBANY</city><state>NY</state><zip/><country/><start_date>1989-09-01T00:00:00</start_date><end_date>1992-08-01T00:00:00</end_date><inv_related>0</inv_related><crd_seq_num>4</crd_seq_num></employment></employment_history>
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath does not have a sort or ordering feature, for that you need XQuery or XSLT.